# Generating nxn array in numpy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I can generate an array like this :

```
arr = np.array(range(0,36))
arr
#Output
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
   17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
   34, 35])
```

My question is how can I generate nxn array like:

```
array([[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], 
[18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
[30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've written that output doesn't look right, bit if you mean a 6x6 array then:

```
>>> arr = np.array(range(0,36)).reshape((6,6))
>>> arr
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])
```

Note there's an outside set of square brackets here compared to your desired output...

A slightly more compact (`.reshape` can take multiple args) and possible quicker way (`np.arange` thx @jadsq):

```
 np.array(np.arange(36)).reshape(6,6)
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean the same. Thanks.

Comment: Use `np.arange` instead of `range`, it works the same and should be much faster